# Pandas - sorting dataframe by max value row-wise

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df
            artist                     track     pos     neg     neu
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better    0.07    0.93     0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming    0.05    0.95     0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You    0.05    0.95     0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk    0.08    0.92     0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars    0.03    0.97     0.0
7       Aphex Twin                Avril 14th    1.00    0.00     0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah    0.39    0.61     0.0
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day    0.09    0.91     0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing    0.09    0.91     0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity    0.03    0.97     0.0
6        Radiohead                     Codex    1.00    0.00     0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?    0.00    1.00     0.0
```

which I'm sorting according to closeness to `input_value = 0.8`

like so:

```
    v = df[['pos', 'neg', 'neu']].values
    df.iloc[np.lexsort(np.abs(v - input_value).T)]
```

which yields:

```
    artist          track                      pos     neg          neu
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day   0.09    0.91          0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing   0.09    0.91          0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk   0.08    0.92          0.0
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better   0.07    0.93          0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You   0.05    0.95          0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming   0.05    0.95          0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity   0.03    0.97          0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars   0.03    0.97          0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah   0.39    0.61          0.0
6        Radiohead                     Codex   1.00    0.00          0.0
7       Aphex Twin                Avril 14th   1.00    0.00          0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?   0.00    1.00          0.0
```

but given an `input_label = 'neg'`

I would like to insert a condition that `if input_label = 'neg'`,

then `neg` value must be the highest value `row-wise`,

eliminating rows accordingly if condition is not satisfied,

ending up with:

```
    artist          track                      pos     neg          neu
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day   0.09    0.91          0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing   0.09    0.91          0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk   0.08    0.92          0.0
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better   0.07    0.93          0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You   0.05    0.95          0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming   0.05    0.95          0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity   0.03    0.97          0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars   0.03    0.97          0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah   0.39    0.61          0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?   0.00    1.00          0.0
```

how do I do this?

Comment: I'm not really able to follow your question. It looks like you eliminated row index 6 and 7. I see that the neg values for both of those rows are 0, but I have no idea how that relates to what you're aiming at. Looks like all you're looking to do is a boolean mask. df[df['neg']==input_label]

Comment: I'm aiming at keeping only correctly labeled items in dataframe. if `pos` values are highest on the row, these items don't belong here. I need `neg`tracks. so my aim is to: 1) reorder dataframe by difference, then 2) eliminate wrong entries.

Comment: temp = df[df['neg'] - df['pos'] > 0] will give you the subset of records where neg is greater than pos.  Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes, minding that 'neg' must be > than 'neu' as well. if you amswer, I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
v = df.iloc[:, -3:]
df = df.iloc[np.lexsort(np.abs(v - input_value).T)]
```

---

You can use `df.query` here, should simplify things.

```
result = df.query('neg > pos and neg > neu'); result
            artist                     track   pos   neg  neu
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day  0.09  0.91  0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing  0.09  0.91  0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk  0.08  0.92  0.0
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better  0.07  0.93  0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming  0.05  0.95  0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You  0.05  0.95  0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars  0.03  0.97  0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity  0.03  0.97  0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah  0.39  0.61  0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?  0.00  1.00  0.0
```

---

Alternative solution with `np.argmax`:

```
mask = np.argmax(df.iloc[:, -3:].values, 1) == 1

mask
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
        True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

result = df[mask]; result    
            artist                     track   pos   neg  neu
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars  0.03  0.97  0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah  0.39  0.61  0.0
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better  0.07  0.93  0.0
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day  0.09  0.91  0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing  0.09  0.91  0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk  0.08  0.92  0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You  0.05  0.95  0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity  0.03  0.97  0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?  0.00  1.00  0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming  0.05  0.95  0.0
```

---

You can sort your `df` on index, using `sort_index`:

```
result.sort_index()
            artist                     track   pos   neg  neu
0   Sufjan Stevens  Should Have Known Better  0.07  0.93  0.0
1   Sufjan Stevens      To Be Alone With You  0.05  0.95  0.0
2     Jeff Buckley                Hallelujah  0.39  0.61  0.0
3   Sufjan Stevens        Death with Dignity  0.03  0.97  0.0
4   Sufjan Stevens       Casimir Pulaski Day  0.09  0.91  0.0
5        Radiohead        Desert Island Disk  0.08  0.92  0.0
8        Radiohead               Daydreaming  0.05  0.95  0.0
9   Sufjan Stevens            The Only Thing  0.09  0.91  0.0
10       Radiohead       You And Whose Army?  0.00  1.00  0.0
11   Elliott Smith          Between the Bars  0.03  0.97  0.0
```

Comment: maybe a solution with Argmax would be best, because I need to use variables -such as `input_label` instead of strings. I need to satisfy the condition for the variable..

Comment: @data_garden Sure.